# Is it type of a plagiarism?

Tags: thesis, plagiarism

I have a question about plagiarism: are these two sentences plagiarised versions of each other?

In a cited paper, it says:

> This paper describes the design for a novel passive mechanical knee-ankle prosthesis that provides knee flexion during swing to provide additional toe clearance that makes the device safer.

Can I use the sentence like given below? I will use it in state-of-the-art part of introduction where I give examples of studies:

> Knee flexion was provided by the prosthesis at swing motion.

Answer (score 2):

First, it isn't plagiarism if you cite it. Plagiarism means using someone else's work as if it were your own. What you have done is *paraphrase* something from the paper. This is allowed as long as it is accurate. Your statement seems a bit too definite, however. The paper makes claims and provides some evidence, I suspect, but it is a bit strong to state it as you did - as if the papers claims are correct in every respect.

Maybe:

"According to [1], Knee flexion was ..."

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Some of the words are necessary if you want to be accurate.

Comment: For something that detailed, you might as well use a direct quote, along with the citation. Put it in quotes as you have done here.

Comment: I wouldn't think it necessary. If your advisor suggests changes you can make a few others as well.

Comment: glad to help. Good luck in your future.